# ¿Como definir el ancho a una tabla y a sus th ? para que se vean igual en Google Chrome y Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap, css3, datatables

Estoy realizando un proyecto donde muestro diferentes tablas y quiero definir el ancho a las tablas y sus th, en Google Chrome me funciona correctamente pero cuando lo pruebo en Firefox no me toma en cuenta el ancho de la tabla

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:3000px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style=" width: 50px;">ITEM</th>
<th style=" width: 150px;">TIPO ORDEN</th>
<th style=" width: 100px;">N° ORDEN</th>
<th style=" width: 150px;">FECHA ORDEN</th>
<th style=" width: 100px;">REQUERIMIENTO</th>
<th style=" width: 100px;">CLIENTE</th>
<th style=" width: 200px;">FAMILIA SERVICIO</th>
<th style=" width: 500px;" >SERVICIO ESPECIALIZADO</th>
<th style=" width: 150px;">COD. PROYECTO</th>
<th style=" width: 200px;">EMISOR</th>
<th style=" width: 150px;">AREA EMISOR</th>
<th style=" width: 100px;">REFERENCIA</th>
<th style=" width: 200px;">NOMBRE PROVEEDOR</th>
<th style=" width: 150px;">FORMA PAGO</th>
<th style=" width: 170px;">FECHA ENTREGA</th>
<th style=" width: 150px;">LUGAR ENTREGA</th>
<th style=" width: 150px;">AUTORIZADO POR </th>
<th style=" width: 100px;">MONEDA</th>
<th style=" width: 150px;">TOTAL ORDEN</th>
<th style=" width: 100px;">OPCIONES</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Materiales</td>
  <td>001</td>
  <td>2018-04-02</td>
  <td>Requerimiento 1</td>
  <td>Alicorp</td>
  <td>Tanques</td>
  <td>Fabricación y Montaje de Tanque de Almacenamiento</td>
  <td>proyecto 1</td>
  <td>Crusura Chavez Iberico</td>
  <td>Administración</td>
  <td>Prueba</td>
  <td>Comercial Capillo</td>
  <td>Cash</td>
  <td>2018-04-02</td>
  <td>Obra</td>
  <td>Asistente de Gerencia</td>
  <td>Soles</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-view btn-xs"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default"> </td>
  </tr>
  
</tbody>
</table>
```

toma en cuenta la anchura definida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto técnicamente hablando no es un problema de FireFox, el problema está en que las tablas las renderizan de manera diferentes cada explorador, y para tener compatibilidad con todos los exploradores hay que asignar una serie de argumentos de estilos, pero en tu caso particular lo que resolvería este problema sería asignar estos dos estilos:

```
width: 3000px;
min-width: 3000px;
```